# How to display the final returned value from a Python program in terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, return

I'm simply writing a Python program that takes in 2 integers and returns the sum. The problem I encounter is that the terminal never displays the returned value, so I have to resort to making a print statement. Is there any way to have the terminal display the returned value of the program?

The code is as follows:

```
import argparse

def simple_addition():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Simple Addition Program to Test CLI")

    # each line add AN argument to our terminal inout
    parser.add_argument("first_number", type = int, help = "enter the first integer")
    parser.add_argument("second_number", type = int, help = "enter the second integer")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # storing the entered argument internally within our code for ease of access
    first = args.first_number
    second = args.second_number

    # calculate and return the sum
    sum = first + second
    print("A PRINT CALL (not return): ", sum)
    return sum

simple_addition()
```

Following is a screenshot of the terminal when I run this program.

[image: Screenshot of the terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

def simple_addition():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Simple Addition Program to Test CLI")

    # each line add AN argument to our terminal inout
    parser.add_argument("first_number", type = int, help = "enter the first integer")
    parser.add_argument("second_number", type = int, help = "enter the second integer")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # storing the entered argument internally within our code for ease of access
    first = args.first_number
    second = args.second_number

    # calculate and return the sum
    sum = first + second
    #print("A PRINT CALL (not return): ", sum)
    return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(simple_addition())
```

1. add shebang on first line and `chmod +x`
2. do not print inside the function
3. do it only if it's main (so you can import the module if needed)

then you can invoke it directly

```
./"CLI Testing.py" 35 45
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did points 2 and 3 of yours, and it worked! I don't quite understand point 1 though, can you elaborate on what is "shebang" and what is chmod +x? I'm guessing "shebang" is the first line that you added in the code?

Comment: Right. The first line plus `chmod +x "CLI Testing.py"` (you can also remove the `.py`) allows you to run it just using its name (no need to invoke `python3 script-name` just `script-name`)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to have the terminal display the returned value of the program?

Yes, by using `print`. That's what it's for.

> so I have to resort to making a print statement

You do not "resort" to it in the same way as you  do not "resort" to the `+` operator in order to add two numbers. It's just what it's there for.

It's true, however, that printing *and* returning the result from a function is not good design (for example, it prevents you from reusing the function in cases where you don't want to print the result).

Instead of printing the result from *inside* the function it would be better to print the *returned value* in the calling code:

```
print(simple_addition())
```

or

```
result = simple_addition()
print(result)
```